# Create a php file individually

Tags: php, html, file

Well, the code I have below creates all of the files in one go, instead of going through 1, then 2, then 3, then 4 then so on

```
$i = 0;
while($i < $pages)
{
    $met = $this->articles();
    $myFile = trim($met.".php");

    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("Can't create files.");
    $stringData = "<html><head><meta name=\"description\" content=\"" . $met. "\" />
                   <meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"" . $met . "\" /><h1>" . $met . "</h1>
                   <base href='http://gumpic.com/'>".$this->show_web("http://gumpic.com")."</html>";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);
    $i++;
}

echo "We've created your " . $pages . " pages.";
```

How would I go by loading the page, the printing on the page what pages have been completed? like;

1. Complete
2. Complete
3. Complete
4. Pending

Also, is there anyway I can speed this script up. it's awfully slow, only creates 2k files in about 3 minutes and then gives me an internal error.

Comment: You can [click the edit link under your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12280263/edit) if you want to fix errors like that.

Comment: May I know the use case here?

Comment: @NateCorky Edited to make it `2K`.

Comment: Your HTML doesn't have a closing `<head>` tag, nor an opening or closing `<body>` tag.. Why generate so many static files when you can generate dynamic pages?

Comment: @nick — Those tags are all optional in HTML.

Comment: @Quentin Looks cleaner when you close all the opened tags.. :)

Comment: I don't want to link to my website, but http://gumday.com/rand.php see, it doesn't show page created untill the whole script has loaded then is shows all of the pages created, instead of going 1,2,3,4,5 is just waits for them all

Answer (score 0):

The speed of this script is dependant on the hard drive speed mainly. Also how well the OS treats opening and write access.

If you want a progress showing just include an `echo("Processing ".$i."\n");` in the `while` loop and flush the buffer with `flush()`. Make sure to send `echo str_repeat(" ", 1024), "\n";` at the script start to force the browser to display content without waiting for a large amount of data.

Use `set_time_limit()` to give your script more processing time.

Comment: Hi, where would I put flush? and it's still just showing the loading page.

Comment: immediately after the echo instruction. flush() forces the buffer empty so content is sent to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using some templating language, because allocating and chaining your output every time surely has bad performance.

Some good libraries would be:

- [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) [my usual pick];
- [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/);
- [TI](http://phpti.com/) [pure PHP, handful for smaller purposes];

Consider writing a command line tool if you are not already doing - echoing to console will be faster than writing to screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
ob_start();
$i = 0;
while($i < $pages)
{
    $met = $this->articles();
    $myFile = trim($met.".php");

    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("Can't create files.");
    $stringData = '<html>
                    <head>
                        <meta name="description" content="' . $met. '" />
                        <meta name="keywords" content="' . $met . '" />
                    </head>
                    <body>     
                    <h1>"' . $met . '"</h1>
                   <base href="http://gumpic.com/">'.$this->show_web("http://gumpic.com").'</body>
                  </html>';
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);
    echo 'Created page ' . ($i+1) . '<br/>';
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    $i++;
}

echo "Done generating " . $i . "pages.";
```